# adding facebook share button to a dynamically generated web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, api, twitter

I need to add facebook twitter and google +1 button to a dynamically generated web page. 
I am explaining my use case here:

User comes to my web portal which is a java/j2ee based web portal and adds few content (e.g. name,address, company, designation, place and also his picture.)

Then, I am generating a page like facebook profile page, www.mydomain.com/user_name.

So my goal is to add his contents along with the url and picture to his/her facebook wall using facebook share button.

I went through few codes that I got, one simple example is:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location=%22http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.location)+%22&#38;t=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.title)" title="Share on Facebook..."><img src="/path/to/your/image/" width="12" height="12" alt="alt" /></a>
```

Can I enhance the same code to get my needs done? Also I need to twitter the same content. But I am not able to do it dynamically. How do I do that? Any reference or tutorials or code sample would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" 
   data-url="http://your.url.com/yourdynamicpage" 
   class="twitter-share-button" 
   data-text="What should I share?" 
   data-count="horizontal">
Tweet
</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

This will work

Comment: nice thanks a lot, hope I will be able to add dynamic content to this example

Comment: sure! It doesn't restrict anything :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dynamically generating a web page, that means you are filling the content with data taken from either `get` / `post` or a database.

If you are already using this data to fill in other content, why would you not be able to use this data to populate the parameters of the Facebook share url?

Comment: I will be able to do it, I got the point I have one more Issue, I am not able to get the facebook share button. I am not able to figure out, whats wrong in the code